# How to use tastypie for multilingual API in Django?

Tags: django, tastypie

I am using django-transmeta for internalization of my models. It is working very well. It is saving the models into the database like this:

```
name_en, name_de, name_tr ...
```

so when you need object.name, it returns the name in current locale, whic is very good for my task.

I am using tastypie for the RESTful API. Tastypie returns all columns of the table (name_en, name_de, name_tr). What I want is, making a request like :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/object/?format=json&lang=en

So server should response only the name (not name_en, name_de, name_tr) in English.

How can I do that? What tastypie function, customization can handle this?

Update:

```
 def dehydrate_title(self, bundle):
        return bundle.data['title'].upper()
```

Something liked that can be a solution?

Comment: Yes, you could use ModelResource but explicitly define fields, i.e. name instead of name_en for example. Then use dehydrate_name or just dehydrate to retrieve proper value from the database. The lang keyword can be taken care of where the format is determined. You may want to look at the source of tastypie.resources for ideas, but it would work. Good luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below model solved my problem. Thank you kgr!

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from padmenu.item.models import Item
from django.utils.translation import activate
from tastypie import fields


class ItemResource(ModelResource):
    name = fields.CharField()
    description = fields.CharField()
    class Meta:
        queryset = Item.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'item'
        excludes = ['name_tr', 'name_de', 'name_en', 'description_tr', 'description_de',   'description_en']

def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    lang = str(bundle.request.GET.get('lang'))
    activate(lang)
    bundle.data['name'] = bundle.obj.name
    bundle.data['description'] = bundle.obj.description
    return bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the same problem, but I've solved it in another way:

```
######## settings.py #########

gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('uk', gettext('Ukrainian')),
    ('ru', gettext('Russian')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)

######## api.py #########
exclude_fields = set('_' + lang[0] for lang in settings.LANGUAGES)

class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        cls = MyModel
        queryset = cls.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'mymodel'
        excludes = [field for field in cls._meta.get_all_field_names() if field[-3:] in exclude_fields]
```

The current language is handled by 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', so there is no need to activate it manually.